# What are the steps needed to set up wireguard on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, wireguard

I have installed wireguard on a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04 but I am unsure of what needs to be done after the install

Comment: Do you want to install the server or the client software?

Comment: I would say both if that is what is necessary to make witeguard functional.

Comment: Is there a wireguard manual that outlines the steps ND procedures?

Answer (score 2):

Installing WireGuard on Ubuntu 18.04 is relatively simple thanks to the efforts of the people behind the project. WireGuard has a PPA repository that is well maintained. You can add this PPA and the recommended prerequisites like this:

#### Configuring the Server

0. Open Terminal (if it’s not already open)
1. Add the WireGuard PPA (not required for versions 20.04 and above):

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:wireguard/wireguard
   ```
2. Update Apt for the new repository:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   ```
3. Install WireGuard plus some recommended prerequisites:

   ```
   sudo apt install wireguard software-properties-common
   ```

   Once installed, you should see something like this:

   ```
   wireguard:
   Running module version sanity check.
   Original module
   No original module exists within this kernel
   Installation
   Installing to /lib/modules/5.3.0-46-generic/updates/dkms/
   depmod…
   DKMS: install completed.
   ```
4. With WireGuard installed, it’s time to configure it and create the encryption keys that will allow the tool to operate securely:

   ```
   wg genkey | sudo tee /etc/wireguard/privatekey | wg pubkey | sudo tee /etc/wireguard/publickey
   ```

   As the commands suggest, `genkey` generates the private key and `pubkey` generates the matching public key.

   The next step will be to create a tunnel device that will route the VPN traffic. This can be done using the `ip` or `wg` commands. However, for easier management, you can create a tunnel file and add its configurations within.
5. Run the commands below to create a tunnel file called `wg0.conf`:

   ```
   sudo vi /etc/wireguard/wg0.conf
   ```

   ***Note:** Feel free to use any text editor that you prefer. The use of `vi` here is more muscle memory than an explicit endorsement.*
6. Paste this to the file:

   ```
   [Interface]
   Address = 10.0.0.2/24
   SaveConfig = true
   ListenPort = 51820
   PrivateKey = {paste private key here}
   PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enp0s3 -j MASQUERADE
   PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o enp0s3 -j MASQUERADE
   ```

   Be sure to replace `{paste private key here}` with the actual private key generated by WireGuard in the previous step, and `enp0s3` with the device that will listen for connections. You can find this information with `ip a`.
7. Bring the tunnel online:

   ```
   sudo wg-quick up wg0
   sudo systemctl enable wg-quick@wg0
   ```

   You will see output that looks something like this:

   ```
   [#] ip link add wg0 type wireguard
   [#] wg setconf wg0 /dev/fd/63
   [#] ip -4 address add 10.0.0.2/24 dev wg0
   [#] ip link set mtu 1420 up dev wg0
   [#] iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enp0s3 -j MASQUERADE
   ```

   You can verify the tunnel is in place with this command:

   ```
   sudo wg show wg0
   ```

   This will show something along the lines of:

   ```
   interface: wg0
   public key: vGzuXr0nETkqGLg6abrVSCDe4C6tO5eWcIE8gdpRMAk=
   private key: (hidden)
   listening port: 51820
   ```

   Now on to some port forwarding …
8. Open the `sysctl.conf` file for editing:

   ```
   sudo vi /etc/sysctl.conf
   ```

   If you are using an IPv4 address, then uncomment the line that reads: `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`. If you are using an IPv6 address, uncomment the line that reads `net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1`. This should give you a section that looks something like this:

   ```
   # Uncomment the next line to enable packet forwarding for IPv4
   net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
   # Uncomment the next line to enable packet forwarding for IPv6
   #  Enabling this option disables Stateless Address Autoconfiguration
   #  based on Router Advertisements for this host
   #net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1
   ```
9. Save the file. Then run these commands to complete the WireGuard Server setup:

   ```
   sudo sysctl -p
   sudo ufw allow 51820/udp
   ```

   This will reload `sysctl` and allow port 51820 through the firewall.

#### Configure the Client

Next up is the client that will connect to the server. The first few steps will look familiar, as we need to add the necessary PPA, then install the base software:

1. Open Terminal (if it’s not already open)
2. Add the WireGuard PPA, update Apt, and install:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:wireguard/wireguard
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt install wireguard software-properties-common
   ```
3. Generate the private and public security keys:

   ```
   wg genkey | sudo tee /etc/wireguard/privatekey | wg pubkey | sudo tee /etc/wireguard/publickey
   ```
4. Create a `wg0.conf` file:

   ```
   sudo vi /etc/wireguard/wg0.conf
   ```
5. Paste this base into the new file and customize accordingly:

   ```
   [Interface]
   PrivateKey = {Client Private Key}
   Address = 10.0.0.2/24


   [Peer]
   PublicKey = {Server Public Key}
   Endpoint = {Server IP}:51820
   AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
   ```

   ***Note:** Be sure to replace `{Client Private Key}` with the key that was just created and recorded in your `/etc/wireguard/privatekey` file, `{Server Public Key}` with the public key recorded on the server, and `{Server IP}` with the accessible IP address of the server.*

#### Finally …

The last step is to let the server know about the client that will come calling at some point. So, back in terminal on the server, run:

```
sudo wg set wg0 peer {Client Public Key} allowed-ips 10.0.0.2
```

Again, be sure to replace `{Client Public Key}` with the public key from the client.

Back on the client …

Now you can bring up (or reset) the interface and check the connection:

```
sudo wg-quick up wg0
sudo wg
```

If everything is properly connected, you should see something like:

```
interface: wg0
  public key: sZThYo/0oECwzUsIKTa6LYXLhk+Jb/nqK4kCCP2pyFg=
  private key: (hidden)
  listening port: 48052
  fwmark: 0xca6c

peer: r3imyh3MCYggaZACmkx+CxlD6uAmICI8pe/PGq8+qCg=
  endpoint: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:51820
  allowed ips: 0.0.0.0/0
  latest handshake: 15 seconds ago
  transfer: 28.88 KiB received, 47.74 KiB sent
```

If you wish to disconnect from the tunnel, you can issue this command:

```
sudo wg-quick down wg0
```

There are a lot of steps here for Ubuntu 18.04, and it’s *much* simpler in newer releases, but this will give you everything you need to run WireGuard on Ubuntu. If you want to connect to your server from Windows, macOS, or a plethora of other Linux/BSD distros, [you can download the client software direct from WireGuard](https://www.wireguard.com/install/).

Hope this gives you what you need.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Can you tell me what these lines are doing? Postup and postdown